# How to select only one LI element at time with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What this does is it selects the LI items from the list, but I want it to be able to only choose one at a time. For instance if I click Vaje and then Projekt, the Vaje one should revert back to normal and so on and so forth, even for the added user inputs.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.class', function(){ 
  $(this).css("font-weight", 'bold'); 
  $(this).css("text-decoration", 'underline'); 

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#add").click(function(){
      var addItem= $("#dodaj").val();
      if(addItem.length > 0){
        $("ul").append('<li class="class">'+ addItem + '</li>');
        $("#dodaj").val("");
      }
    });
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id = "dodaj" name="additem">
<button id="add" onclick="newElement()">Dodaj</button>
<button id="remove" >Zbriši</button>

<ul id="kategorija" >
  <li class="class">Vaje</li>
  <li class="class">Treningi</li>
  <li class="class">Projekt</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the click you are setting "bold" and "underline" for one li, but you are not resetting the other elements. You can change the click event to:

```
$(document).on('click', '.class', function(){ 
    // reset all li
    $('.class').css("font-weight", 'normal');
    $('.class').css("text-decoration", 'none');

    // now set the current li
    $(this).css("font-weight", 'bold'); 
    $(this).css("text-decoration", 'underline');
});
```